# How do I point my login page to the database instead of the web.config credentials?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, authentication, authorization

I have a log in page created and I have used the ASP.NET configuration tool to create two users with passwords.

When I try and log in with the created users I get invalid username/password error that I setup. The problem is I know I am typing the exactly the way that I set them up. I can however; go to the

```
 <credentials>
        <User>
 </credentials>

 <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="SqlRoleProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="SqlRoleProvider" applicationName="UCX" connectionStringName="UCXDBConnectionString"
         type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>

  <authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="3">
    <credentials passwordFormat="Clear">
      <!--<user name="admin" password="password"/> If I uncomment this I can access site. -->
    </credentials>
  </forms>
</authentication> 

    <authorization>
  <allow roles="Admin" />
</authorization>
<membership
           defaultProvider="SqlProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="20">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="SqlProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="UCXDBConnectionString" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" />

  </providers>
</membership>
```

In my web config and if I log in with that user I am able to access the site. This however is very bad for what we want. I have checked the database and the users are there. I just cannot access them.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure your site to use the ASP.NET SQL Server Membership Provider. See here for more: http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/security/membership/creating-the-membership-schema-in-sql-server-cs

Comment: After reading through the tutorial I found that I have all of those steps covered any other suggestions?

Comment: If you have followed all the steps exactly, and your MVC app has read rights on your database, it should work fine. If it doesn't, I think you should verify whether your application can read any data from that database.